# почему не верно срабатывает условие?

Tags: javascript

```
var h =100;
var t =100;
while ((h<=0) || (t<=0))    {
... цикл операции на уменьшение значение h или t...
} else if (h<=0) {alert('h параметр = 0');
} else if (t<=0) alert('t параметр = 0');
```

почему то логический оператор `||` или срабатывает не срабатывает.
только когда оба условия `(h<=0) (t<=0)` равны 0 выходит из цикла.
Мне бы пример как можно выйти из цикла когда одна из переменных <= 0
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: код большой слишком. Идет вычитание из переменных, не равномерное. и когда одна из них будет <= 0 Должен произойти выход.

Comment: срабатывает выход когда, одна из переменных уходит в - а вторая = 0.

Comment: в приведенном коде синтаксическая ошибка: нельзя писать `while (...)    {

} else`. выбросьте все ненужное из вашего кода и предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Вы же написали  `только когда оба условия (h<=0) (t<=0) равны 0 выходит из цикла` ..... а теперь `одна из переменных уходит в - а вторая = 0`  ....надо бы определиться) и лучше показать код больше, чем есть.....иначе это все гадание на картах таро

Comment: эм. Там все нужное. Мне бы пример как такое реализовать можно. 'else if' не обязателен, это от незнания сделано.

Comment: я писал что переменные не равномерно уменьшаются. Могут сильно разниться в значениях. Это как один из вариантов на правильного срабатывания.

Comment: @Данил, Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. как создать [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы прервать выполнение цикла можно использовать [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

Проверяете внутри цикла нужное условие и вызываете `break;`

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 10;

while (i <= 10 || j <= 10) {
  document.write('<div>i=', i, '</div>');
  i += 1;
  if (i == 5) break;
}

document.write('<div>Complete</div>');
```

Comment: мне цикл с двойным условием нужен.

Comment: @Данил, с чего вы взяли? :-) вы же не предоставили код. Судя по всему он и так работает как надо. и в крайнем случае можете использовать прием из ответа.

Comment: @Данил, вот пример с двойным - никакой разницы

Answer (score 0):

> Мне бы пример как можно выйти из цикла когда одна из переменных <= 0

```
while ((h>0) && (t>0)) {
... цикл операции на уменьшение значение h или t...
}
if (h<=0)
  alert('h параметр <= 0');
if (t<=0) 
  alert('t параметр <= 0');
```

Comment: && - это логический оператор и а мне нужен или. Нужно что бы срабатывало если одно из уловий будет верно.

Comment: @Данил, цикл будет выполняться пока `h` и `p` больше 0. Как только одна из них станет меньше или равно 0 цикл завершиться. Разве вам не это нужно?